# Can I make the data of an entire C++ class be std::atomic<>

Tags: c++, c++14, stdatomic

I havea class, used for data storage, of which there is only a single instance.

The caller is message driven and has become too large and is a prime candidate for refactoring, such that each message is handled by a separate thread. However, these could then compete to read/write the data.

If I were using mutexes (mutices?), I would only use them on write operations. I don't think that matters here, as the data are atomic, not the functions which access the data.

Is there any easy way to make all of the data atomic? Currently it consists of simple types, vectors and objects of other classes. If I have to add `std::atomic<>` to every sub-field, I may as well use mutexes.

Comment: "_If I were using mutexes (mutices?), I would only use them on write operations._": That's probably wrong. If a read happens while a write under mutex lock happens, that is also a data race.

Comment: Why are you determined to avoid mutexes?

Comment: `std::atomic` can only be used with trivially copyable types. You need a mutex at least with vectors.

Comment: Even if all your members were trivially copyable, most data structures have some sort of consistency requirements among the members.  Making everything atomic doesn't prevent two members from being temporarily out of sync, and having some thread read them both in that invalid state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::atomic` requires the type to be trivially copyable. Since you are saying `std::vector` is involved, that makes it impossible to use it, either on the whole structure or the `std::vector` itself.

The purpose of `std::atomic` is to be able to atomically replace the whole value of the object. You cannot do something like access individual members or so on.

From the limited context you gave in your question, I think `std::mutex` is the correct approach. Each object that should be independently accessible should have its own mutex protecting it.

Also note that the mutex generally needs to protect writes *and* reads, since a read happening unsynchronized with a write is a data race and causes undefined behavior, not only unsynchronized writes.